# Get child view from a ListView within a ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I have a ListActivity with a ListView populated onStart with data from a database. Each row is a custom view. After the ListView is populated I want to select a specific row and edit it (for example change the background).

If I try getListView().getChildCount() after it is populated I always get 0. Am I misunderstanding how getChildCount works or have I used it incorrectly?

Comment: Check what `getCount()` returns and if it is 0.

Comment: When are you calling getChildCount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to select a row (click a row) and change the background color, this could work:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#444444"));

                    }});
```

If you are trying to do programmatically on population, you should override your list adapter and do it in there.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I am trying to do it programmatically. I am using a SimpleAdapter to populate the list. How do I go about overriding it?

Comment: Ignore that, i think i have answered my own comment. I found this http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/ and it seems to be what i am after. :)